# How to install the "google" module for Python in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, pip, python3

I have a hard time installing the `google` module on my Python 3.6.4, or actually having Python seeing it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -V
Python 3.6.5

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade google
Requirement already up-to-date: google in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -c "import google; print(google.__file__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

**How should I install the `google` module so that it is visible by Python?**

Comment: What is the google module, Google search from Python ?

Comment: @f14284: it is a module which simplifies the authentication and manipulation of the Google APIs. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) are a mess, though. They reference the module `google-api-python-client`, and then suddenly the module `google` (which is the one I am trying to tame)

Comment: Them did you try it with the other (`google-api-python-client`)?